# Can't close workbook after copy data to another

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to run a macro and i'm stuck,:

1. Run a script that saves data from SAP on a excel file (file.xlsx) in desktop
2. Then copy that data and pastes it on an existing sheet from another workbook (file2.xlsm)

The problem is that the file.xlsx stays open and i can't make it to close

```
Sub atualizarretornos()



Set SapGuiAuto = GetObject("SAPGUI")
Set objGui = SapGuiAuto.GetScriptingEngine
Set objConn = objGui.Children(0)
Set session = objConn.Children(0)


session.findById("wnd[0]").maximize
session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/okcd").Text = "/n"
session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/okcd").Text = "vl06o"
session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/btnBUTTON6").press
session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 17
session.findById("wnd[1]").sendVKey 8
session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 8
session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 43
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/ctxtDY_FILENAME").Text = "retornos pendentes.xlsx"
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/ctxtDY_FILENAME").caretPosition = 23
session.findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[11]").press


Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim wbkretorno As Variant

wbkretorno = "C:\Users\lopesa04\Desktop\retornos pendentes.xlsx"

Workbooks.Open wbkretorno
Set wbkretorno = ActiveWorkbook

wbkretorno.Worksheets(1).Range("A:P").Copy

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("retornos pendentes")
        .Range("A:P").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    End With
    
    
ActiveWorkbook.Save


ActiveWorkbook.Close


Sheets("Sheet1").Activate

Application.ScreenUpdating = True


End Sub
```

thanks

After paste the data the inicial workbook closes.

Comment: Why are you using the same variable `wbkretorno` for both the filepath and the actual workbook object? Then, why are you using `ActiveWorkbook` in `ActiveWorkbook.Save` and `ActiveWorkbook.Close`, instead of your workbook variable?

Comment: It looks like the problem is that the line "ActiveWorkbook.Close" is closing the wrong workbook. Instead of using "ActiveWorkbook", try using the variable "wbkretorno" that you defined earlier to refer to the workbook that you want to close. So replace "ActiveWorkbook.Close" with "wbkretorno.Close". This should close the correct workbook, "retornos pendentes.xlsx".
Also, you might want to include a check whether the file is open or not before you close it. You can use the function "Workbooks.CanClose" to check if the workbook can be closed without saving changes.

Comment: @Zen, your comment is really an answer, not a comment. Posting it as a comment leaves the question as unanswered, causing people trying to help (like you and me) wasting time browsing on already answered question that divert focus on the real unanswered question.

Answer (score 2):

ActiveWorkbook is not fixed, it changes depending on the actions in your program , when you Open the workbook with

```
Workbooks.Open wbkretorno
Set wbkretorno = ActiveWorkbook
```

"C:\Users\lopesa04\Desktop\retornos pendentes.xlsx" becomes the ActiveWorkbook, but later when you do :

```
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("retornos pendentes")
        .Range("A:P").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    End With
```

ThisWookbook (the one with the macro) becomes the ActiveWorkbook.

So when you do

```
ActiveWorkbook.Save
ActiveWorkbook.Close
```

It refers to the workbook with the macro, not to the one with SAP data. If you want to close the one with SAP data you should do what @zen suggested:

```
wbkretorno.Save
wbkretorno.Close
```

EDIT - after your last comment try changing this, do not use the same variable for 2 different things, the name and the workbook object

```
Dim wbkretorno As Variant

wbkretorno = "C:\Users\lopesa04\Desktop\retornos pendentes.xlsx"

Workbooks.Open wbkretorno
Set wbkretorno = ActiveWorkbook
```

with

```
Dim wbkretorno As Workbook

Workbooks.Open "C:\Users\lopesa04\Desktop\retornos pendentes.xlsx"
Set wbkretorno = ActiveWorkbook
```

Saludos

Answer (score -1):

I tried to put before:

wbkretorno.Save
wbkretorno.Close

But the workbook wbkretorno = "C:\Users\lopesa04\Desktop\retornos pendentes.xlsx", just insist on staying open.

Comment: If this is not a full, correct response, it belongs in the question. Please append this note to your question and delete this response.

Answer (score -1):

I think it as something to do with the time of the macro, it runs to fast.
If i run the macro with the F8 key line by line, it does what it's suppose.

Comment: If this is not a full, correct response, it belongs in the question. Please append this note to your question and delete this response.